# How can I use linq to go from an array of indices to a collection of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, collections

My title question is a little vague, since it's hard to ask, but my situation is this:

I have an array of ints, which are indices into a separate collection of objects.

The array looks like this:

```
int[] indices = { 0, 2, 4, 9, 10, 11, 13, /* more (non-)sequential indices */ };
```

Each of these indices corresponds to an object at that index in a collection I have.

I want to be able to build a new collection of these objects using the indices in my array.

How would I do that using some LINQ functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] indices = { 0, 2, 4, 9, 10, 11, 13 };
string[] strings = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q" };

IEnumerable<string> results = indices.Select(s => strings[s]);

// or List<string> results = indices.Select(s => strings[s]).ToList();

foreach (string result in results) // display results
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Of course change strings etc to your collection of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
List<int> items = Enumerable.Range(1,100).ToList();
int[] indices = { 0, 2, 4, 9, 10, 11, 13, /* more (non-)sequential indices */ };
var selectedItems = indices.Select( x => items[x]).ToList();
```

Basically for each index in your collection of indices you are projecting to the corresponding item in your `items` collection (whatever type those items are) using the indexer.

If your target collection is just an `IEnumerable<SomeType>` than you can alternatively use `ElementAt()` instead of an indexer:

```
var selectedItems = indices.Select(x => items.ElementAt(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wish I could accept multiple answers, sometimes I feel bad not being able to accept every single working answer. :(